# Discriminant function of 1 Nearest Neighbor

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis, k-nearest-neighbour

Consider the following question:

We will consider the case of 1-nearest neighbor, and look at the details of computing the error probability. In this case, let us assume that we have two classes, $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{2}$, with equal priors. That is, $P(\omega_{1}) = P(\omega_{2}) = 0:5$. Now, consider the data coming from the two following distributions:

$P(x|\omega_{1}) = \begin{cases}
2x,  & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$} \\
0 ,  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$P(x|\omega_{2}) = \begin{cases}
2(1-x),  & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$} \\
0 ,  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

What is the discriminant function for this classification?

What is the classification error?

---

I am familiar with the Linear discriminant analysis via the bayes classifier, however since there is no sense of priors in KNN, how does this process change in the case of 1 nearest neighbor.

Comment: How can be P(x|omega1)=2x for 0<=x<=1?  It means that for x>0.5, P(x|omega1)>1, which is impossible!  Same for P(x|omega2).

Comment: Then according to that, the decision boundary is ay 0.5? Also x is a vector.

Comment: If x is a vector, what does it mean that P(x|omega1)=2x ?

Comment: x is a feature vector, and p (x|omega) is the probability we match x features given target class omega, it is the likelihood.

Comment: the probability is found by taking the area under the curve of f(x). At least this is how im understanding this problem.